# Entity Framework Code First: How can I model this simple referral scenario?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to model what seems like a relatively simple referral scenario. I've tried to search but I'm not exactly sure what the name is for the kind of relationship I am looking to create.

**Here is the explanation:**

One student can refer another student to the school. Therefore each student can refer many students and each new student can only be referred by one existing student.

**Here is the code:**

```
// Model
public class Student
{
    public int? ReferralID { get; set; }
    public virtual Referral Referral { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
}

public class Referral
{
    public int ReferringStudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Student ReferringStudent { get; set; }

    public int ReferredStudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Student ReferredStudent { get; set; }
}

// Context
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Referral)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferralID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Referrals)
    .WithRequired(x => x.ReferringStudent)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferringStudentID);
```

**Here is the resulting database:**

[image: Missing a key]

**Question:**

What can I do to get Entity Framework to recognize that ReferringStudentID should be a foreign key? I've tried using the fluent API to describe the relationship from the Referral to the Student but the results are the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is EF tries to create foreign keys with cascade deletes. Your referral table has two not nullable foreign keys to student table. That will form multiple delete paths if you delete a student. This is not allowed by SQL Server.

Change your foreign key mapping with `ReferringStudentID` as follows

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Referrals)
            .WithRequired(x => x.ReferringStudent)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ReferringStudentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You need to think how you are going to keep referential integrity if you allow to delete students.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm too accustomed to EF warning me about multiple delete paths that I didn't take it upon myself to even consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with code first, admittedly.  It appears to me, though, that you are creating two classes when you only need one.  If I were designing this structure in SQL DDL, it would look something like

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    StudentId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ReferredBy INT NULL REFERENCES Students (StudentId)
)
```

I don't recall whether I would be able to include the self-referential foreign key in the CREATE TABLE statement or whether it would be required to create the foreign key constraint separately.

I'm not sure exactly how to translate to code-first EF, but I think you will only want one class rather than two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This could work, however there are a few more properties for the Referral class that apply only to the Referral and not to the Student. I'd rather not put them on the Student class since they really don't belong there.

Comment: I would say its a good db design have referrals in a table alone, it make space for a powerful information about (and of) referrals and you even dont need to lookup the user table (unless you need user specific data). I think the foreign key studentid just need to be unique, so it only can exist once. It means that a student are referred, when its referred.